# Simple get method javadoc

Tags: java, integer, comments, javadoc

I am new in Java and I want to ask a simple question about Javadoc comments. Lets say I have a simple method :

`public int getNumber()`

The Javadoc comment would be **@return A number** OR **@return int A number** ?

Comment: If your question is whether you need to include the return type in your `@return` information, then no. The return type is part of the signature of the method. It doesn't need to be respecified.

Comment: @khelwood So, it doesn't matter the type of the method? Even if the method would be `public float getNumber()` , the javadoc would still remain **@return A number** correct?

Comment: "A number" is a pretty useless description. But as I said, you don't need to respecify the return type. Even if it is a float.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, I know! I used this description for a more generic example. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

for good techniques on writing javadocs.

You don't need to specify "int" in your @return annotation. Since this is part of the signature of the method and can be inferred from there. A more accurate thing to do would be describing what kind of number you are returning, i.e: explain what that number is.

Here's an example you can use:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to specifically state the return type of the method because it is part of the method's signature. So the Javadoc comment would just be **@return A Number**. However if the return type was void you do not need to include an **@ return** comment.

Here is a good article about Javadoc comments if you are interested in learning more: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Edit: Just realized someone else posted this ^ link earlier but it is still a good source :)